# Avoid code repeating when use dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following code snippet:

```
short adults, teens, children;

dict.TryGetValue("ADT", out adults);
dict.TryGetValue("TEEN", out teens);
dict.TryGetValue("CHD", out children);

ServiceModel.Set(adults, teens, children);
```

where dict is populated instance of Dictionary type.

I firmly believe that this could be rewritten in non-repeatable way. 
Any idea how?
Thank you in advance

Comment: No. It can't... What code is repeating anyway?

Comment: `TryGetValue` returns a boolean to indicate success. You should be checking this. If you are certain the keys exist, you can `dict["ADT"`]`.

Comment: Actually it seems that dict.TryGetValue is repeated three times, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah that's how it has to happen.

Comment: @spender I am not certain whether dict["ADT"] comes populated.

Answer (score 1):

You replace your code by :

```
ServiceModel.Set(dict["ADT"], dict["TEEN"], dict["CHD"]);
```

Comment: Nope. ServiceModel.Set(...) is function call and dict itams are not mandatory.

Comment: @user576700 How about : `ServiceModel.Set(dict.ContainsKey("ADT") ? dict["ADT"] : 0,  dict.ContainsKey("CHD") ? dict["TEEN"] : 0, dict.ContainsKey("CHD") ? dict["CHD"] : 0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to get this shorter. You have to access the dictionary three times, no matter how hard you try to 'optimize'. And why would you? These lines are necessary to get the values out.

One suggestion though, since you don't apply `TryGetValue` correctly. Usually you check if the return value is `true` to indicate success. If not successful, you can set the value to a default.

If the items must be in the dictionary, you can simply use:

```
adults = dict["ADT"];
```

If the entries are not mandatory, your code should include assigning a default value.

Comment: As I mentioned, items are not mandatory in this dictionary, that is why I am using TryGetValue here.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method that provides a default value in the absence of a key:

```
public static class DictEx
{
    public static TVal GetValueOrDefault<TKey, TVal>(
        this IDictionary<TKey, TVal> dict, TKey key, TVal defaultValue = default(TVal))
    {
        TVal val;
        return dict.TryGetValue(key, out val) ? val : defaultValue;
    }
}
```

and use it with your `Dictionary<string,short>`

```
dict.GetValueOrDefault("nonexistentKey") //returns default(short) (0)
dict.GetValueOrDefault("nonexistentKey", 1000) //returns 1000
dict.GetValueOrDefault("existingKey", 1000) //returns value, default is ignored
```

This, in turn, would mitigate the risk of uninitialized variables that currently exists in your code.